# SQL - How do I declare a group of people's names to be used in my query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause, having, declare

I have 5 queries that I will be running all at the same time to return 5 different groups of data - what they do all have in common is my statement below:

```
HAVING  (   LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%BRIAN%MILLER%') OR 
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%LATEASHA%CALVERT%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%CHERITA%MARTIN%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%CARMALITA%MCQUEEN%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%CRAIG%NADRATOWSKI%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%SCOTT%SMOLINSKI%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%ALISHA%WILLIAMS%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%SHANNON%MURPHY%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%MICHELLE%COLE%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%ROGER%KONKEL%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%DANIELLE%JONES%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%SABRINA%WARNER%') OR
        LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE ('%CORINNE%DUBETZ%'))
```

I would like to define these people at the beginning of my query to be used later in a having statement or where statement, basically saying

```
HAVING (left(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-',comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE [anyone that I've already defined above]
```

I'm not sure if this is even possible or if so how I would even go about it.  Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: You could store those names in a temp table, then use a WHERE IN (Subquery of temp table)

Comment: Put them in a temporary table/table var, you can inner join using LIKE.

Comment: This doesn't seem proper of a HAVING, try also moving to the WHERE.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I forgot to mention that I don't have rights to create temp tables - query bombs out. :O

Comment: Moving to Where essentially accomplishes the same thing for me here - just takes it longer to run for some reason... so I've left it in having.  Point is in this, if someone leaves this team, or is added, I don't want to have to update the name list in 5 places, i'd like to just do it once. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: What about a table variable instead of a #temp table

Comment: I'm listening, @AlexK. How do I make this happen if you have time to go into detail?

Comment: As in `declare @PEOPLE table (name varchar(128)); insert @PEOPLE values ('%BRIAN%MILLER%'),('%LATEASHA%CALVERT%'),('%CHERITA%MARTIN%') ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Alex K's comment, you can start out with the table variable:

```
DECLARE @People TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(128)); 
INSERT @People VALUES ('%BRIAN%MILLER%'),('%LATEASHA%CALVERT%'),('%CHERITA%MARTIN%')
```

Now Let's say that I have a **Member** table and I need to find the members in this table based on your criteria, the query might look like this (I'm just grouping by name to conform to your example):

```
SELECT 
    M.[Name]
FROM 
    mem.Member M
GROUP BY 
    M.[Name]
HAVING 
    (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @PEOPLE P WHERE M.Name LIKE P.Name))
```

More specifically for your example:

```
SELECT 
    comm.[LONG_COMM_LINE_1]
FROM 
    comm
GROUP BY 
    comm.[LONG_COMM_LINE_1]
HAVING 
    (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @PEOPLE P WHERE  LEFT(comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1, CHARINDEX('-', 
comm.LONG_COMM_LINE_1) - 2) LIKE P.Name))
```

[Here is the docs on **EXISTS** for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Another option is using a CTE that is referenced multiple times. The only problem is that it can only be used on that statement.

Comment: Yea CTE is also an option. But I would think if the table is going to have a long life time like hinted at in mark's comment "Point is in this, if someone leaves this team, or is added, I don't want to have to update the name list in 5 places" then I would honestly just put it in a normal table. CTE and TABLE variable almost implies it's a once-off thing which this comment tells me it's not.